# "Activation of network connection failed." Always Shows Up

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, printing

I've setup a print server in our office using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and successfully setup CUPS o be available over the network to all devices.

The problem is, every time I'm trying to connect to our router, it keeps showing "Activation of network connection failed." error. I tried also directly connect the server to our router via ethernet and still shows the same error message.

What seems to be the problem here and how can I fix it? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I have run `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` as @waltinator suggested and managed to get the following output:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2022-04-07 12:00:24 PST, end at Tue 2022-04-19 09:28:53 PST. --
Apr 19 09:26:25 vurd-ps systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Apr 19 09:26:29 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331589.5266] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Apr 19 09:26:29 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331589.5267] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity->
Apr 19 09:26:30 vurd-ps systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Apr 19 09:26:30 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331590.2855] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Apr 19 09:26:30 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331590.8931] wifi-wext: (wlx30b5c2205d6f): driver supports SSID scans (scan_capa 0x3F).
Apr 19 09:26:30 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331590.8932] wifi-wext: (wlx30b5c2205d6f): using WEXT for Wi-Fi device control
Apr 19 09:26:30 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331590.9961] manager[0x556324562030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Apr 19 09:26:30 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331590.9962] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Apr 19 09:26:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331591.3285] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Apr 19 09:26:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331591.3286] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "vurd-ps"
Apr 19 09:26:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331591.3293] dns-mgr[0x556324546290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Apr 19 09:26:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331591.3303] manager[0x556324562030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Apr 19 09:26:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331591.3304] manager[0x556324562030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.7066] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-devi>
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.7324] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-devic>
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.7719] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-devic>
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.8021] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device>
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.9091] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-devic>
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.9097] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.9102] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.9104] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Apr 19 09:26:32 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331592.9106] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Apr 19 09:26:33 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331593.3712] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/lib>
Apr 19 09:26:33 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331593.3713] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Apr 19 09:26:33 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331593.3714] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Apr 19 09:26:33 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331593.3714] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Apr 19 09:26:33 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331593.3714] ifupdown:       interface-parser: source line includes interfaces file(s) /etc/network/interfaces>
Apr 19 09:26:33 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331593.3715] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Apr 19 09:26:34 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331594.4439] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Apr 19 09:26:34 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331594.4447] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Apr 19 09:26:34 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331594.4474] manager: (enp2s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Apr 19 09:26:34 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331594.7393] settings: (enp2s0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Apr 19 09:26:34 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331594.7488] device (enp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'exte>
Apr 19 09:26:35 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331595.1952] manager: (wlx30b5c2205d6f): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Apr 19 09:26:35 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331595.1959] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-sta>
Apr 19 09:26:36 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331596.9684] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Apr 19 09:26:36 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331596.9685] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Apr 19 09:26:38 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331598.0468] sup-iface[0x55632456f100,wlx30b5c2205d6f]: supports 1 scan SSIDs
Apr 19 09:26:38 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331598.0474] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Apr 19 09:26:38 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331598.0475] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available>
Apr 19 09:26:38 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331598.4579] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Apr 19 09:26:40 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331600.2864] modem-manager: ModemManager not available
Apr 19 09:26:40 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331600.3108] modem-manager: ModemManager now available
Apr 19 09:26:41 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331601.1949] manager: startup complete
Apr 19 09:26:59 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331619.9133] agent-manager: agent[50dbb79eee5130ee,:1.53/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7334] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): Activation: starting connection 'THIS_IS_OUR_WIFI' (207ca623-66f>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7338] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="207ca623-66f6-43c6-994a-b6f1b2082ad2" name="Victory Urdanet>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7342] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: >
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7351] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7360] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'manag>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7363] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): Activation: (wifi) access point 'THIS_IS_OUR_WIFI' has security,>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7363] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'man>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7381] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'ma>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7383] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'manag>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7385] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): Activation: (wifi) connection 'THIS_IS_OUR_WIFI' has security, a>
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <error> [1650331686.7385] wifi-wext: (wlx30b5c2205d6f): error setting powersave 0
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7385] Config: added 'ssid' value 'THIS_IS_OUR_WIFI'
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7385] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7385] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7386] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Apr 19 09:28:06 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331686.7386] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Apr 19 09:28:07 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331687.1326] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Apr 19 09:28:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <warn>  [1650331711.9439] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Apr 19 09:28:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331711.9440] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-stat>
Apr 19 09:28:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331711.9448] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 19 09:28:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <warn>  [1650331711.9463] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): Activation: failed for connection 'THIS_IS_OUR_WIFI'
Apr 19 09:28:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331711.9471] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: '>
Apr 19 09:28:31 vurd-ps NetworkManager[598]: <info>  [1650331711.9499] device (wlx30b5c2205d6f): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: ubuntu can be so awful.  This thing keeps popping up every 20 seconds like malware.  Is there anyway to stop it?